# Events get unbound when I destroy slider

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I need to update the slider's range and number formatting (format option) depending on user input.
Since the format is not among the options I can update with updateOptions method I have to destroy the slider and create a new one. But the events I hooked the original slider to stop working although the docs say that 'events are not unbound when destroying a slider' https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/
What's wrong with my code? Is there a way to bound the events back?

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [ 1000000 ],
    step: 1000,
    connect: 'lower',
    range: {
        'min': [  500000 ],
        'max': [ 5000000 ]
    },
   format: rubleFormat
});

//code's getting redundant, I repeat it. Will fix later
function updateSlider(currency) {
  if(currency == 'USD') {
    slider.noUiSlider.destroy();
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: [ 10000 ],
        step: 100,
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
            'min': [  5000 ],
            'max': [ 300000 ]
        },
       format: dollarFormat
    });
  }
  else {
    slider.noUiSlider.destroy();
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: [ 1000000 ],
        step: 1000,
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
        'min': [  500000 ],
        'max': [ 5000000 ]
        },
      format: rubleFormat
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `rubleFormat` and `dollarFormat` are instances of `wNumb`, you can switch out the formatter. Set `format` to cast to a `Number`:

```
var currentFormatter = rubleFormat;

function updateSlider(currency) {
    currentFormatter = currency === 'USD' ? dollarFormat : rubleFormat;
    slider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({ /* ... */ });
}

slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle){
    input.value = currentFormatter.to(values[handle]);
});

input.addEventListener('change', function(){
    slider.noUiSlider.set(currentFormatter.from(this.value));
});
```

This will be **way** more performant than rebuilding the slider, too.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/5vshz44r/2/).

Comment: Lg102, thank you. But it looks like I'm too stupid to get this. As I understand you overwrite the original get method and what does it begin to do? How does it begin to work?

Comment: Tried it. I created the slider and left the `format` option empty. Then I pasted your code and tried to update the slider with the `updateOptions()` method to change the range. The update works but the slider now ignores the format https://jsfiddle.net/artdeev/5vshz44r/  I don't know what to do with it. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated your example as per the description you gave.